# Associate role to RDS instance that already exists using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

i'm new to using the CDK. I want to do exactly the same thing described in this [discussion](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/discussions/20276), however i don't want to create the RDS instance as it already exists. How can i add the IAM Role to an already existing RDS instance?

Answer (score 2):

If the RDS instance already exists, and is not controlled through CloudFormation and/or the CDK, then you have two options:

1. Import the RDS instance into a CloudFormation stack, letting the stack take ownership of the RDS and manage it going forward. You can find additional information [here](https://matthewbonig.com/2021/08/30/importing-with-the-cdk/).
2. Use a Custom Resource to make an API call to add the IAM role.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would the second option work?

Comment: Custom Resource -> Lambda, Lambda makes an API call: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_AddRoleToDBCluster.html